# gstremer plugin ffdec_h264 is missing after installing gst-libav package codebase

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg, gstreamer, h.264

My system is Ubuntu 15.04 64 bit.

I have downloaded https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-libav/gst-libav-1.8.3.tar.xz 
and performed below steps.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
```

every thing looks fine.

Now when i check

```
gst-inspect-1.0 ffdec_h264
No such element or plugin 'ffdec_h264'
```

I understand that ffdec_h264 gstreamer plugin is part of **gst-libav-1.8.3.tar.xz** and after installing that i do not get that plugin.

what steps i am missing.

Comment: Did you try `gst-inspect ...` in a "new" terminal window? The PATH or other env-vars may not be up to date in the installing terminal window. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter yes i have also tried the same but no luck in that also. I am missing something.

Comment: you may get an answer here, but I would look for a support forum specific to gstreamer and post there. Good luck.

Comment: Maybe because the plugin is now called 'avdec_h264'? also what is the output of gst-inspect-1.0 | grep *h26*?

Comment: @SamerTufail thanks guys. I have followed http://wiki.oz9aec.net/index.php/Building_Gstreamer_1.2_from_source and now it worked fine.

Comment: great, mark as answered and close please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did not know what happened last night.

On Fresh morning today, I have blindly followed this steps and now its works fine.

http://wiki.oz9aec.net/index.php/Building_Gstreamer_1.2_from_source

Yes as Samer suggested now `ffdec_h264` is as `avdec_h264`.